# Amplification of the P-component

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, simulation, simulink

Given again in this simulation is an unknown system. This time the excitation source is not known. In addition, the P, I and D components are not shown individually in the scope, but summed up.
are shown.

Now you see the scope and my question is how I find the "amplification of the p-component " ?

Given is also the "Latency", "pulse height" and "pulse duration".

Please help me my dear friends of engineering. :)

[image]

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version).